# Wordpress TinyMCE broken (ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED): How to define TinyMCE in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I recently moved my WordPress website. The site works fine but the admin does not load the TinyMCE editor. This disables me from editing text.

Here is my console simplified:

```
GET domain/wp-includes/js/tinymce/wp-tinymce.php?c=1&ver=4310-20160418 net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined

Here is the extended version:

 GET ..domain/wp-includes/js/tinymce/wp-tinymce.php?c=1&ver=4310-20160418 net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED (post.php?post=100&action=edit:2844)

Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined(anonymous function) @ post.php?post=100&action=edit:2846

    Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined(anonymous function) 
    @ wp-langs-en.js?ver=4310-20160418:235(anonymous function) @ wp-langs-en.js?ver=4310-20160418:519
    post.php?post=100&action=edit:2841 


Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not definedload_ext @ post.php?post=100&action=edit:2841(anonymous function) @ post.php?post=100&action=edit:2851
```

It would be great help if someone can tell me if I can manually define TinyMCE.

[image: Console]

Answer (score 0):

It's a common error. Probably you have tinymce.js in specified path in wp-includes. But some reasons cause to prevent load tinymce.js . tinymce.js is loaded by tinymce.php and tinymce.php includes this logic:

```
if ( isset($_GET['c']) && 1 == $_GET['c'] && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'])
    && false !== stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip') && ( $file = get_file($basepath . '/wp-tinymce.js.gz') ) ) {

    header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
    echo $file;
} else {
    // Back compat. This file shouldn't be used if this condition can occur (as in, if gzip isn't accepted).
    echo get_file( $basepath . '/tinymce.min.js' );
    echo get_file( $basepath . '/plugins/compat3x/plugin.min.js' );
}
```

There is a compressing error most probably, something prevents your WordPress to compress tinymce.

In my case, I solved this error by disabling LiteSpeed Cache. LiteSpeed Cache doesn't work in my hosting plan so it causes compressing problem at wordpress loading.

Hope this answer helps others.